# Running multiple Node files from batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I have a situation where I need to rerun the same process 5 times (performance testing). Basically I am using this :

```
@echo off  
cd "E:\Performance\CpuTest"
start /wait npm install
start /wait node index.js
start /wait node index.js
start /wait node index.js
start /wait node index.js
start /wait node index.js
```

Issue is this `"start /wait npm install"` stalls the whole thing as It runs installs the packages if missing but then the newly opened `cmd` where `npm` install was launched remains open and waits for me to close it then it moves to next line. If I remove the wait on it then it runs and closes but at the same time the Node js script starts running aswell.

Any solutions ?

Comment: I don't get the issue. You don't want the rest of the script to wait for `npm install` but then if you remove the wait, it does not do what you want either? Please edit and better explain your issue.

Comment: Actually " stalls the whole thing as It runs installs the packages if missing but then CMD is waiting for me to close"  It does npm install but then the cmd is sitting cause of the /wait i have to manually close it and then other run

Comment: Yes, because you are telling it to wait. but I am still not sure what your issue is. Do you want it to wait or not?

Comment: It does wait but after completion it does not close the cmd and its just sitting i have to manually close it then other run.

Comment: then do `call npm install` also, `npm` on windows is a `cmd` file, so better to `call npm.cmd install`

Comment: perfecto! :) works

Comment: And change `cd "E:\Performance\CpuTest"` to `cd /D "E:\Performance\CpuTest"` to also change the drive in case…